# Difference between

Tags: solidity, return

I am going through Patrick Collins' course on Youtube and was confused why the following code works. Separate from the low-level stuff he's doing here, why does `getSelectorOne()` work in the `callTransferFunctionFunction` within `abi.encodeWithSelector`? It doesn't return anything (and therefore should return 0) yet works in the video. Doesn't `getSelectorOne` need to return the `selector` variable?

```
function getSelectorOne() public pure returns (bytes4 selector) {
    selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
}

function callTransferFunctionDirectly(address someAddress, uint256 amount)
        public
        returns (bytes4, bool)
{
    (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
        // getDataToCallTransfer(someAddress, amount);
        abi.encodeWithSelector(getSelectorOne(), someAddress, amount)
    );
    return (bytes4(returnData), success);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, the `returns` declaration creates a variable that can be used inside of the function. This part:

```js
returns (bytes4 selector)
```

The `selector` variable declared here is an actual variable that can be used inside of the function and assigned value to. And the function will auto return this function implicitly if it is not returned explicitly or another value is not returned explicitly to override the implicit return of the `selector` variable.

So, when that function does:

```js
selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
```

It is actually assigning the value to the `selector` variable declared in the `returns` area.

You could also do this, returning explicitly:

```js
    function getSelectorOne() public pure returns (bytes4 selector) {
        selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
        return selector; 
    }
```

But is not necessary if you declared the `selector` variable in the `returns` part, since declaring the variable like `returns (bytes4 selector)` will return that variable implicitly.

You could also do something like this:

```js
    function getSelectorOne() public pure returns (bytes4 selector) {
        bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
        return selector; 
    }
```

Besides declaring `returns (bytes4 selector)`, creating a new `bytes4 selector` inside the function and assigning it a value and returning it, but you will get a warning telling you that this new variable is shadowing an existing `selector` variable declared in the `returns` area.

You could also do this:

```js
    function getSelectorOne() public pure returns (bytes4 selector) {
        bytes4 selector2 = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
        return selector2; 
    }
```

Create a variable with a different name (selector2) and assign it a value and return it. In this case, the `selector` variable declared in the `returns` area will be ignored and the value you explicitly `return` is the one that will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

It does. The variable is declared at function declaration

```
... returns(bytes4 selector) {
```

when you do that (naming a return variable at function declaration) that variable gets initialized and whatever's in there at the end of execution is returned. Here, the function only has one line, which happens to be setting this variable to the `transfer(address, uint)` function selector